# How to print first nth characters from a string then first n+1 characters and so on

Tags: python, string

This is what I have so far:

```
def generateCosets(str, n):
    equalStr = []
    for i in range(0, n):
        part = getNthLetters(str, n)
        equalStr.append(part)
    return equalStr


def getNthLetters(text, n):
    builtstring = ''
    for i in range(0, len(text)):
        if i % n == 0:
            builtstring = builtstring + text[i]
    return builtstring
```

If I run this code:

```
s0 = '12345678'
myArr = generateCosets(s0,2)
print(myArr[0], myArr[1])
```

it yields:

```
1357 1357
```

instead of:

```
1357 2468
```

I just don't know how to make the for loop start from i+1 every time I use the getNthLetters method

Comment: You can just do `print(s[0::2], s[1::2])`

Comment: you can also check if is even or Odd: number % 2 == 0

Answer (score 0):

you can use slicing on string

```py
s0[0::2]
'1357'
s0[1::2]
'2468'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by checking the parity of the indexes at your initial string:

```
s0 = '12345678'
print(''.join([i if int(i)%2 != 0 else "" for i in s0]), ''.join([i if int(i)%2 == 0 else "" for i in s0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use slice notation *(check [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211/10824407))* with step:

```py
def generate_cosets(text, n):
    for i in range(n):
        yield text[i::n]
```

Usage:

```py
s0 = '12345678'
print(*generate_cosets(s0, 2))
```